# How to send app request using FBNativieDIalogs in facebook-ios-sdk 3.1.1 framework?

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-app-requests

I want to send app request to facebook friends of user. I am using facebook-ios-sdk 3.1.1 framework. There is

```
 [FBNativeDialogs presentShareDialogModallyFrom:self.parentViewController initialText:@"Some text..." image:nil url:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.apple.com"] handler:nil];
```

But this presents dialog for feed & not for app request. And FBWebDialogs is not there in sdk 3.1.1. framework.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Sayali

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
[FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]
            message:@"Check this app" title:nil parameters:params handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
              if (error) {
                  // Case A: Error launching the dialog or sending request.
              } else {
                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                      //Case B: User clicked the "x" icon
                  } else {
                      //Case C: Dialog shown and the user clicks Cancel or Send
                  }
              }
        }];
```

Comment: FBWebDialogs is not there in facebook sdk 3.1.1 framework. I have mentioned this in question above.

Comment: Yes i just did that & updated facebook framework to 3.5.1 & it worked. But SDK 3.1.1 do not have FBWebDialogs

Comment: Alternately you have fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
[FBWebDialogs
     presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:nil
     message:@"Learn how to make your iOS apps social."
     title:nil
     parameters:nil
     handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {}
];
```